# When the data that Apollo fetched is ready with React & GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, promise, graphql, apollo-client

1. I want to render a calendar component (named `Calendar`) that will start with initial values (`events`), based on a GraphQL query.
2. When a user press a button, `Calendar` will get only some of the events (no addition query required) and will rerender.
   I managed to do each of them separately, but not both:

For (1): render only when data is ready, not using states, then can't accomplish (2).
For (2): using states but then can't accomplish (1).

The code below is pretty straight forward:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

const requestsQuery = gql`query requestsQuery { ... }

class MainComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        events: []
      };
      // here i want to know when the data that apollo fetched is ready
      // and then i will create events (using the data)
      // and then:
      // this.setState({events: events});
    }

    renderLoader() {
      return (
        <div>
          Loading...
        </div>
      );
    }

    onItemClick(){
      // make some events
      this.setState({events: events});
    }

    renderCalendar(){
      return (
        <Calendar events={this.state.events}/>
      );
    }

    renderRows(requests) {
      return (
        requests.map((request) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {request.displayName}
              <button onClick = {this.onItemClick.bind(this, request)}>show only some events</button>
            </div>
          );
        })
      );
    }

    render() {
        const { loading, requests } = this.props;

        return (
          <div>
            {loading
                ? this.renderLoader()
                : <div>{this.renderRows(requests)}</div>
            }
          </div>
        );
    }
}

const MainComponentWithData = graphql(requestsQuery, {
  props({ ownProps, data: { loading, requests } }) {
    return {
      loading,
      requests
    };
  }, })(MainComponent);
```

Inside the `render()` method i know when loading is false, hence, data is ready, but i don't know how to do it elsewhere.

If i initialize events in the `renderRows(requests)` and then use `this.setState({events: events})` react will rerender forever.

The Question: How do I accomplish (1) AND (2)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you want to fetch the events from GraphQL. And when you click on the AnotherComponent item you want to refetch.

One possibility to set a state from a query is to use the componentWillReceiveProps functionality.
But it is not recommended to combine states and props.

An example:

```js
...
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (!newProps.<query name>.loading) {
       ...
       this.setState({events: events});
    }
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks! why isn't recommended to combine states and props? do you recommend maybe a different architecture to achieve this?

Comment: Here is a link for some further reading about using props to initialize states [react Anti-Pattern](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e#.3r4jfbxup).
A possibility would be that you get all the relevant data in the query and create the events that you send to the Calendar element in the render function. Now when you press onClick you set a single state (kind of "month", "day") with which you select other values from the first query